# One Page navigation animation

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, navigation

I'm using One Page Nav Plugin (https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) to create my one page navigation. I want to animate my menu labels from bottom to top, and top to bottom with absolute top, and bottom values, but I just can't figure out how to achieve this

This is code responsible for setting top value

```
  var iHeight = $(this).outerHeight() + 5;

  element += iHeight;
  $(this).css({
    top: element,
    position: 'absolute'
  });
```

Then reset top value:

```
scrollChange: function($currentListItem) {
  setHeight();
  $currentListItem.prevAll().addClass('selected');
  $currentListItem.nextAll().removeClass('selected').css({
    top: 'auto'
  });
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3n5ncjkk/10/

Comment: I would make a switch of plugin and switch to FullPage.js, this automatically supports navigation and is rich with features while remaining small in size.. Refer to http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/